Question about observer pattern. How about there is an observer need information from two or more sources
I just carefully studied the observer pattern. And I wrote a demo snippet to better undertand it.
But after I just finished the demo, a question arose, the observer pattern is between one obserable objects and many observers. How about there is an observer need information from two or more sources?
Here is the demo code written in C++ to make you understand my quesiton better(Please pay attention to my comment in the code snippet below):
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class IObserver;

class IObservable
{
public:
    virtual void add(IObserver*) = 0;
    virtual void remove(IObserver*) = 0;
    virtual void trigger() = 0;
    virtual double get_temperature() = 0;
    virtual ~IObservable() = default;
};

class IObserver
{
public:
    IObserver(IObservable& observable):m_observable(observable){}
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual ~IObserver() = default;
protected:
    IObservable& m_observable;
};

class IDisplay
{
public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual ~IDisplay() = default;
};

class WeatherStation : public IObservable
{
public:
    void add(IObserver* observer_ptr) override
    {
        if(std::find(m_observer_list.begin(), m_observer_list.end(), observer_ptr) == m_observer_list.end())
        {
            m_observer_list.push_back(observer_ptr);
        }
    }

    void remove(IObserver* observer_ptr) override
    {
        m_observer_list.erase(std::remove(m_observer_list.begin(), m_observer_list.end(), observer_ptr), m_observer_list.end());
    }
    
    void trigger()
    {
        for(const auto& observer:m_observer_list)
        {
            observer->update();
        }
    }

    double get_temperature()
    {
        return m_temperature;
    }

    void set_temperature(double temperature)
    {
        m_temperature = temperature;
        trigger();
    }

    virtual ~WeatherStation() = default;
private:
    std::list<IObserver*> m_observer_list;
    double m_temperature;
};

class CommonDisplay:public IObserver, public IDisplay
{
public:
    CommonDisplay(IObservable& observable):IObserver(observable){}

    virtual ~CommonDisplay() = default;

    void update() override
    {
        display();
    }

};

class PhoneDisplay:public CommonDisplay
{
public:
    PhoneDisplay(IObservable& observable, const std::string& name): m_name(name),CommonDisplay(observable){}

    void display() override
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s phone displayed, temperature: " << m_observable.get_temperature() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string m_name = "unknown";
};


class WindowDisplay:public CommonDisplay
{
public:
    WindowDisplay(IObservable& observable):CommonDisplay(observable){}

    void display() override
    {
        std::cout << "WindowDisplay displayed, temperature: " << m_observable.get_temperature() << std::endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    WeatherStation station_of_NewYork;
    WeatherStation station_of_Seattle;

    PhoneDisplay jone_phone(station_of_NewYork, "Jhone");
    PhoneDisplay lucy_phone(station_of_NewYork, "Lucy");
    station_of_NewYork.add(&jone_phone);
    station_of_NewYork.add(&lucy_phone);

    //If Lucy also what's to know the temperature of Seattle, how to achieve that goal?

    WindowDisplay bedroom_display(station_of_NewYork);
    station_of_NewYork.add(&bedroom_display);

    station_of_NewYork.set_temperature(15.6);
}


It's not limited to observing just one thing. The only reason yours is is that your implementation has that limit.

Changing your reference with vector, and you might have what you want Demo.

If your observables all call the same virtual function update(), you can make an Observer adapter for each to update the main object. For example for observables A and B, make class W with W::updateA() and W::updateB(), and Observer classes ObserveA and ObserveB, where ObserveA::update() just passes through to W::observeA() (and same for ObserveB). Construct W with fields Observer observerA =  ObserverA() (same for B), and pass those to the A and B observables.

@JohnBayko Thank you for the reply. A example code seems make it easy to understand.

@John I think you can make a generic adapter using std::function and std::bind, rather than separate ObserverA and ObserverB adapters, depending on how many adapters you need and how much work you want to put into it.

We can achieve it this way, by subscribing on set of observables (sorry, I couldn't resist doing some refactoring). Here is godbolt link if you need it:
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<sstream>
#include<memory>

class IObserver;

class IObservable
{
public:
    /// @return true if added
    virtual bool add(const std::shared_ptr<IObserver>&) = 0;
    virtual void remove(const std::shared_ptr<IObserver>&) = 0;
    virtual void trigger() = 0;
    virtual double get_temperature() const = 0;
    virtual ~IObservable() = default;
};

class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual ~IObserver() = default;
};

class IDisplay
{
public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual ~IDisplay() = default;
};

class BasicObserver : public IObserver
{
public:
    using observables_container_t = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IObservable>>;

    template<typename IterT>
    BasicObserver(IterT begin, IterT end) 
      : m_observables(begin, end)
    {}

    BasicObserver(const std::shared_ptr<IObservable>& obs)
    {
        m_observables.push_back(obs);
    }

    ~BasicObserver() override = default;
    
protected:
    observables_container_t m_observables;
};

class WeatherStation : public IObservable
{
public:
    ~WeatherStation() override = default;

    bool add(const std::shared_ptr<IObserver>& observer) override
    {
      auto emplacement_info = m_observers.emplace(observer);
      return emplacement_info.second;
    }

    void remove(const std::shared_ptr<IObserver>& observer) override
    {
        m_observers.erase(observer);
    }
    
    void trigger() override
    {
        for(const auto& observer:m_observers)
        {
            observer->update();
        }
    }

    double get_temperature() const override
    {
        return m_temperature;
    }

    void set_temperature(double temperature)
    {
        m_temperature = temperature;
        trigger();
    }
private:
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<IObserver>> m_observers;
    double m_temperature{0};
};

class CommonDisplay:public BasicObserver, public IDisplay
{
public:
    // using ctors from BasicObserver
    using BasicObserver::BasicObserver;

    ~CommonDisplay() override = default;

    void update() override
    {
        display();
    }
};

class NamedDisplay :public CommonDisplay
{
private:
    // using ctors from CommonDisplay
    using CommonDisplay::CommonDisplay;
public:
    ~NamedDisplay() override = default;

    template<typename ...CommonDisplayArgsT>
    static std::shared_ptr<NamedDisplay> make(std::string name, CommonDisplayArgsT&&... args)
    {
      auto display = std::make_shared<NamedDisplay>(std::forward<CommonDisplayArgsT>(args)...);
      display->m_name = name;
      return display;
    }

    void display() override
    {
      std::stringstream tempratures_info;
      for (const auto& obs : m_observables)
      {
          tempratures_info <<  ", temperature: " << obs->get_temperature();
      }
      std::cout << m_name << " displayed" << tempratures_info.str() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

int main()
{
    auto station_of_NewYork = std::make_shared<WeatherStation>();
    auto station_of_Seattle = std::make_shared<WeatherStation>();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WeatherStation>> lucy_stations {
      station_of_NewYork, 
      station_of_Seattle
    };

    auto jone_phone = NamedDisplay::make("Jhone's phone", station_of_NewYork);
    auto lucy_phone = NamedDisplay::make("Lucy's phone", lucy_stations.begin(), lucy_stations.end());

    station_of_NewYork->add(jone_phone);
    for(const auto& station: lucy_stations)
    {
        station->add(lucy_phone);
    }

    auto bedroom_display = NamedDisplay::make("WindowDisplay", station_of_NewYork);
    station_of_NewYork->add(bedroom_display);

    std::cout << "Updating NewYork temprature to " << 15.6 << " ..." << std::endl;
    station_of_NewYork->set_temperature(15.6);

    std::cout << "\nUpdating Seattle temprature to " << 11.1 << " ..." << std::endl;
    station_of_Seattle->set_temperature(11.1);
}

